# Golang GORM one-to-many primary key on custom primary key (string) in parent struct error

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have to structs I want to connect via a one to many relation but it fails with the error

> "invalid field found for struct mygithub/repo field Analytics, need to
> define a valid foreign key for relations or it need to implement the
> Valuer/Scanner interface"

I am using the field "Symbol" as the primary key in my Ticker struct which I guess is where the error is coming from, but how should I progress here to make it to work? I find the GORM documentation very poorly written and can not figure it out myself.

as far as I know I need to define the foreign key in the Analytics struct in the manner of "tickerID" but my field has no primary key that is called like that. I tried to use its PK column name as TickerSymbol but then I get the error.

```
type Ticker struct {
Symbol             string      `json:"symbol" gorm:"unique"`
PriceChange        string      `json:"priceChange"`
PriceChangePercent string      `json:"priceChangePercent"`
WeightedAvgPrice   string      `json:"weightedAvgPrice"`
PrevClosePrice     string      `json:"prevClosePrice"`
LastPrice          string      `json:"lastPrice"`
LastQty            string      `json:"lastQty"`
BidPrice           string      `json:"bidPrice"`
BidQty             string      `json:"bidQty"`
AskPrice           string      `json:"askPrice"`
AskQty             string      `json:"askQty"`
OpenPrice          string      `json:"openPrice"`
HighPrice          string      `json:"highPrice"`
LowPrice           string      `json:"lowPrice"`
Volume             string      `json:"volume"`
QuoteVolume        string      `json:"quoteVolume"`
OpenTime           int64       `json:"openTime"`
CloseTime          int64       `json:"closeTime"`
FirstID            int64       `json:"firstId"`
LastID             int64       `json:"lastId"`
Count              int64       `json:"count"`
Analytics          []Analytics `json:"analytics"`
```

}

```
 type Analytics struct {
   gorm.Model
   Timeframe    string `json:"timeframe"`
   RSI          int    `json:"rsi"`
   TickerSymbol string `json: "tickerSymbol"`
}
```

Comment: The document is clear [this](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Override-References). `gorm:"foreignKey:TickerSymbol;references:Symbol"`.